# Changing the value of a string with a pointer in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I was trying to change the value of the string t_string by passing a pointer of the string to a function and then changing the value of that pointer in the function.

The output I am receiving is the original string "Hello".

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"

void editString(char *theString);

int main() {
    char t_string[] = "Hello\n";
    char *s = t_string;
    editString(s);
    printf("The string after: %s", t_string);
    return 0;
}

void editString(char *theString){
    theString = "Good Bye\n";
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the address of the pointer instead `void editString(char **theString) { *thString = "Good Bye\n" }`, but please note that the resulting string will point to a string literal, while originally it was pointing to an array.

Comment: 'theString = "Good Bye\n";' changes the function parameter, but not the argument at the caller.  C function arguments are passed by value, ie. they're copied into the parameter.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Using your code might cause core dumped since the last few bytes are not allocated properly, right?

Comment: @LionLai No, because reassigning a pointer is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In C, parameters are pass by value.  What you're doing is changing the value of the local variable `theString` to point to a string literal.  That local variable change is not reflected in the calling function.

To change what `theString` points to, use `strcpy`.  That will follow what `theString` points to (i.e. the array in `main`).  Note however that the array isn't large enough to hold the new string, so if you do that you will write past the end of the array and invoke undefined behavior.  So you need to make the array large enough to hold either string.

```
int main() {
    char t_string[20] = "Hello\n";   // enlarge array to hold either string
    char *s = t_string;
    editString(s);
    printf("The string after: %s", t_string);
    return 0;
}

void editString(char *theString){
    strcpy(theString, "Good Bye\n");   // use strcpy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array designators are non-modifiable lvalues. So you can not change an array such a way.

In this statement

```
char *s = t_string;
```

there is created a new object with the name `s` that is initialized by the address of the first character of the array `t_string`.

In this call

```
editString(s);
```

there is created a copy of the value of the argument that is assigned to the function parameter.

You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
editString(s);

//...

void editString(/*char *theString*/){
    char *theString = s; 
    theString = "Good Bye\n";
}
```

So even the argument `s` is not changed by the function. That is at first the local variable `theString` initialized by the value stored in the argument `s` and then this local variable is reassigned by the address of the first character of the string literal `"Good Bye\n"`.

Neither the array `t_string` nor the pointer `s` defined in main were changed in the function.

If you want to change the array you have to assign its characters individually for example by using the standard string function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`. The array has to have enough size to accommodate the new string literal.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"

void editString(char *theString);

int main( void ) 
{
    char t_string[10] = "Hello\n";
    char *s = t_string;
    editString(s);
    printf("The string after: %s", t_string);
    return 0;
}

void editString(char *theString){
    strcpy( theString, "Good Bye\n" );
}
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```